# Equidistant points between two points?

Tags: python, numpy, lerp, linspace

I am trying to know equidistant points between two points.
For example:

```
p1 = (1,1)
p2 = (5,5)
```

The answer that I am expecting is:

```
def getEquidistantPoints(p1, p2, HowManyParts):
    #some code
    return (array with points)
```

In this example, with `p1`, and `p2`:

```
A = getEquidistantPoints(p1,p2,4)
A = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)]
```

Always will be a straight line.
`HowManyParts` in this case is the whole distance that is divided
something like `numpy.linspace()` but in two dimensions.

Comment: If this is supposed to be Python you should use Python syntax, not stuff like `Function` and `//` for a comment.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, I think your example is confusing- is the 3rd parameter supposed to be the number of points found between the two starting points, or is it a number of segments formed by each pair of points?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks to linearity of the line connecting two points, you can simply **use [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy-linspace) for each dimension independently**:

```
import numpy

def getEquidistantPoints(p1, p2, parts):
    return zip(numpy.linspace(p1[0], p2[0], parts+1),
               numpy.linspace(p1[1], p2[1], parts+1))
```

For example:

```
>>> list(getEquidistantPoints((1,1), (5,5), 4))
>>> [(1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0), (4.0, 4.0), (5.0, 5.0)]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed for generating higher (7+) dimensional lines quickly and easily.

Comment: Just replace the return line with 
`zip(*[numpy.linspace(p1[i], p2[i], parts+1) for i in range(len(p1))])`

Comment: @Harsh Nice generalization!

Answer (score 5):

**A pure `Python` solution using `linear` `interpolation`:**

First create a [`linear interpolation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) function:

```
def lerp(v0, v1, i):
    return v0 + i * (v1 - v0)
```

and then just use this to `interpolate` between the `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
def getEquidistantPoints(p1, p2, n):
    return [(lerp(p1[0],p2[0],1./n*i), lerp(p1[1],p2[1],1./n*i)) for i in range(n+1)]
```

and a test with your values:

```
>>> getEquidistantPoints((1,1), (5,5), 4)
[(1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0), (4.0, 4.0), (5.0, 5.0)]
```

Comment: in Python 2, 1/n would evaluate to zero for all n>1, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Grisha Good point,  I hadn't considered that, I have updated the solution now so that it will work for both these versions

Comment: A simple(r) way to get "true division" division in Python 2 code is to add a `from __future__ import division` at the top of the script — which won't hurt even though not needed in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an iterable (tuple, list, etc.). to specify the `start` and the `end` arguments of `numpy.linspace`:

```
p1 = (1,1)
p2 = (5,5)
HowManyParts = 4
A = np.linspace(p1, p2, HowManyParts+1)
print(A)
```

output:

```
array([[1., 1.],
       [2., 2.],
       [3., 3.],
       [4., 4.],
       [5., 5.]])
```

---

You can also use complex numbers:

```
p1 = 1+1j
p2 = 5+5j
HowManyParts = 4
A = np.linspace(p1, p2, HowManyParts+1)
A = np.stack((A.real,A.imag), axis=1)
print(A)
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 1.],
       [2., 2.],
       [3., 3.],
       [4., 4.],
       [5., 5.]])
```